# Open response and send again gone in default Firefox Webconsole

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Since Firebug has been discontinued, I'm missing two very important pieces of functionality.
I was wondering if there is some replacement available for the following functionality within the default Firefox Web Console.

When a URL was called using Ajax, I had the following options with the URL.

- **"Open response in new tab"** Using this I could open errors that were generated after an AJAX-POST call.
- **"Resend query"** I'm not entirely sure what this function was called, because I used it in Dutch but I used this function to retry AJAX-Calls without having to fill in a form again.

So, is there any way to achieve these two functions in the default Firefox Web Console?

Answer (score 2):

You can access to `XHR`s in 2 tabs, `Console` ([Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)) & `Network` ([Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)).

In `Console` you can see quick view of `XHR`s. (*`Headers`, `Params`, `Response`, `Cookies`, `Call Stack`*)

[image]

In `Network` tab you can see all requests incl. `XHR`s. try to select one `XHR` request, you will see a new column show up in left side with following tabs, `Headers`, `Cookies`, `Params`, `Response`, `Timing` & `Preview` (*as Firefox 51.0.1*), check the `Preview` tab, it's great.

Also try to `right-click` on any `XHR` in `Network` tab, you can see few options, incl **Edit and Resend** and **Open in New Tab**. this 2 options will be your answer. :)

You can request features/report bugs about `Firefox Developer Tools` (& of course Firefox) using [Bugzilla@Mozilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). Gaps between Firebug and the Firefox DevTools are tracked in [bug 991806](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806).

Comment: Note that the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) can also display requests *other* than XHRs via the *Net* > *Log* filter. Having said that, the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) is the tool designated for inspecting network requests.

Comment: Second note: *Open in New Tab* currently only makes GET requests, even for POSTs. There's already a [request filed to changed that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220758) behavior to work like in Firebug.